# Need Help to Reduce Processing Time for Large CSV Data

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I've read through some of the previous questions on speed up processing of large CSV data. I've implement some of the ideas and i got some improvement on processing time. However i still need to further cut down the processing time hopefully someone can help me.

I think my code is too long, I'll try to simplify. Here is what my code suppose to do:
1. Read through a csv file.
2. Group the data by first column; calculate total sum of each column and return the result.
**Example (Raw Data):**
        A    B    C
1    2    3
1    2    3
2    4    4
2    4    4
**Result:**
A    B    C
1    4    6
2    8    8
**Note:** My actual data will be 100MB file with 630 columns and 29000 rows, total 18.27M records.

Here is how i achieve it:
**Method 1:**
1. Read a csv file through **Filestream**.
2. Use **Split** to split the returned string and process line by line, field by field.
3. Storing the result in an array and save the result in a text file.

**Note on Method1:** Time to process the data using this method takes ~1 min 20 secs.
**Method 2:**
1. Read a csv file through **Filestream**.
2. Feed the data into different threads before start process. (For now i feed 100 lines of data into different thread, fix 5 threads for now due to CPU resource constraint)
3. Use **Split** to split the returned string and process line by line, field by field in each thread.
4. Join all result from every threads and store in an array. Save the result in text file.
**Note on Method 2:** Time to process the data using this method takes ~50 secs.
So i got ~30secs improvement migrating from **Method 1** to **Method 2**. I was wondering whether what i can do to further improve the process time. I've tried to cut down the data into smaller section like 100 lines x 100 columns and process it but the time to process the data become longer instead.
Hopefully some one can help me on this.
Thank you in advance.
**Edit:**
Here is my code for **Method 2** (I'll skip **Method 1** as i'm not using it already), I have a subroutine that manage the assignment of threads for every 100 lines read from filestream, execute each threads and return the result, finally update the all the results into single array before write the result into file. I tried to make the code as simple as possible. Hopefully this will give more idea to you all on how i process my data.

```
'Subroutine that assign smaller section of raw data into different threads
Sub process_control(byval filename as string)
    Dim sread As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim read As New StreamReader(sread)
    Dim t1 As System.Threading.Thread
    Dim value, data1(), data2(), data3(), data4(), data5(), threadid(), result1(0), result2(0), result3(0), result4(0), result5(0) As String
    Dim row as integer
    Dim rowlimit as integer = 99
    Dim check1 as boolean = true

    row = 0
    check = false
    ReDim data1(rowlimit), data2(rowlimit), data3(rowlimit), data4(rowlimit), data5(rowlimit), threadid(4)
    do
        value = read.ReadLine
        If row < rowlimit + 1 then
            If data1(rowlimit) = "" Then
                 data1(row) = value
            ElseIf data2(rowlimit) = "" Then
                 data2(row) = value
            ElseIf data3(rowlimit) = "" Then
                 data3(row) = value
            ElseIf data4(rowlimit) = "" Then
                 data4(row) = value
            ElseIf data5(rowlimit) = "" Then
                 data5(row) = value
            End If
        Else
            If data1(rowlimit) <> "" And data2(rowlimit) = "" And data3(rowlimit) = "" And data4(rowlimit) = "" And data5(rowlimit) = "" Then
                threadid(0) = ""
                t1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                              result1 = process(data1).Clone
                                              threadid(0) = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                          End Sub)
                t1.Start()
                row = 0
                data2(row) = value
            ElseIf data1(rowlimit) <> "" And data2(rowlimit) <> "" And data3(rowlimit) = "" And data4(rowlimit) = "" And data5(rowlimit) = "" Then
                threadid(1) = ""
                t1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                              result2 = process(data2).Clone
                                              threadid(1) = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                          End Sub)
                t1.Start()
                row = 0
                data3(row) = value
            ElseIf data1(rowlimit) <> "" And data2(rowlimit) <> "" And data3(rowlimit) <> "" And data4(rowlimit) = "" And data5(rowlimit) = "" Then
                threadid(2) = ""
                t1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                              result3 = process(data3).Clone
                                              threadid(2) = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                          End Sub)
                t1.Start()
                row = 0
                data4(row) = value
            ElseIf data1(rowlimit) <> "" And data2(rowlimit) <> "" And data3(rowlimit) <> "" And data4(rowlimit) <> "" And data5(rowlimit) = "" Then
                threadid(3) = ""
                t1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                              result4 = process(data4).Clone
                                              threadid(3) = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                          End Sub)
                t1.Start()
                row = 0
                data5(row) = value
            ElseIf data1(rowlimit) <> "" And data2(rowlimit) <> "" And data3(rowlimit) <> "" And data4(rowlimit) <> "" And data5(rowlimit) <> "" Then
                threadid(4) = ""
                t1 = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                              result5 = process(data5).Clone
                                              threadid(4) = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                          End Sub)
                t1.Start()
                row = 0
                check1 = True
            End If
            row += 1
        End If

        If check1 = True Then
                Do
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                Loop Until threadid(0) <> "" And threadid(1) <> "" And threadid(2) <> "" And threadid(3) <> "" And threadid(4) <> ""
                row = 0
                ReDim data1(rowlimit)
                data1(row) = value
                row += 1
                result1_update(result1) ' consolidate result into a single array
                result2_update(result2) ' consolidate result into a single array
                result3_update(result3) ' consolidate result into a single array
                result4_update(result4) ' consolidate result into a single array
                result5_update(result5) ' consolidate result into a single array
                check1 = False
                ReDim data2(rowlimit), data3(rowlimit), data4(rowlimit), data5(rowlimit)
        End If

    loop until read.endofstream
end sub
```

```
' Function that calculate the sum of each row and columns 
Function process(ByVal data() As String) As String()
        Dim line(), line1(), result() As String
        Dim check As Boolean

        redim result(0)

        For n = 0 To (data.Count - 1)
            if result(0) = "" and result.count = 1 then
                  result(result.count-1) = data(n)
            else
                  check = true
                  line1 = Split(data(n), ",", -1, CompareMethod.Text)
                  For m = 0 to (result.count-1)
                       line = split(result(m),",",-1, CompareMethod.Text)
                       if line1(0) = line(0) then
                            check = false
                            for o = 1 to (line1.count-1)
                                  line(o) = val(line1(o)) + val(line(o))
                            next o
                            result(m) = join(line,",")
                            exit for
                       end if
                  Next m

                  if check = true then
                       redim preserve result(result.count)
                       result(result.count-1) = join(line1,",")
                  end if                
            end if
        Next n

        redim preserve result(result.count-2)
        process = result.clone
End Function
```

Comment: If you're trying to optimise your code you really **must** profile it first to see where the bottlenecks are. If you don't you're just guessing and any improvement in performance is little more than good luck.

Comment: What is the purpose for processing the file? How often do you do this? Would this data be better off saved to a database where queries can be optimized rather than parsing lines of data?

Comment: it would also be handy to see the code as well so we can see how you do the above, many ways to skin a cat

Comment: Check how much time go to reading all file to memory by `FileStream` before processing a data. And ofcourse give us a code if you want help

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedbacks. I'll try to upload my code in a short while.

Comment: Profile first, but one potential optimization is to use a custom number parser http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse-optimization

Comment: @Philip and Mike I'm fairy new to this kind of data processing, can you kindly point me to the correct reading material for this "Profile" method? Just googled this term and i'm kind of lost after some reading. Not sure if i'm reading the right material.

Comment: @OneFineDay Unfortunately I don't have the permission to install databases in the machine that i'm using now for whatever reason that IT give me. So i have to write my own routine to do this & I have tones of files like this to process. I'm actually writing this program in other PC and plan to move the exe file to my work PC to use it.

Comment: @Fabio Tried that and the PC throw me Out of memory exception. I think I have to process it line by line in order to keep the memory usage as low as possible.

Comment: I'm still looking at data profiling stuff available. Do let me know if you guys got any good source for reading... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_profiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I noticed a couple of things:

1. you're using `Val` which is very easy to use but has a high overhead.  `Integer.Parse` would work much more efficiently.
2. You're converting from string to number back to string way more than you should have to.  Since your summary will only be a fraction of the size of your complete data, you shouldn't have any trouble storing the results in memory.  A `Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer())` would work well for this.

Consider this code which will read the data, summarize it and put the data in a format easy to write to a file all in less than 10 secs. using random integers up to 1000:

```
Function SummarizeData(filename As String, delimiter As Char) As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer())
    Dim limit As Integer = 0
    SummarizeData = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer())
    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
        'Since we don't need the first line for the summary we can read it get _
        'the upper bound for the array, and discard the line.
        If Not sr.EndOfStream Then
            limit = sr.ReadLine.Split(delimiter).Length - 1
        Else : Throw New Exception("Empty File")
        End If
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            'This creates an array of integers representing the data in one line.
            Dim line = sr.ReadLine.Split(" "c).Select(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x)).ToArray
            'If the key is already in the dictionary we increment the values
            If SummarizeData.ContainsKey(line(0)) Then
                For I = 1 To limit
                    SummarizeData.Item(line(0))(I) += line(I)
                Next
            Else
            'If not we create a new element using the line as the initial values
                SummarizeData.Add(line(0), New Integer(limit) {})
                SummarizeData.Item(line(0)) = line
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
End Function
```

To use the function and write the data, this would work:

```
Dim results = SummarizeData("data.txt", ","c)
'If you don't need the results sorted you can gain a few fractions of a second by _
'removing the Order By clause
IO.File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", (From kvp In results
                                        Order By kvp.Key
                                        Select String.Join(",", kvp.Value)).ToArray)
```

Comment: some how by replacing those "Val"s in my original code with Integer.Parse makes the process time longer instead (Now 1 min 06 sec to complete process one file). Not sure why i'm seeing this, but i will attempt to restructure my code to follow your structure and see how it perform. Thanks any way.